# Connection error between WooCommerce and Authorize.Net CIM

Tags: woocommerce, authorize.net

I connected a WooCommerce through Authorize.net. Initially the process worked as I have record of a transaction through my bank information.

Then we needed to update the Authorize.net account to CIM. From there, I generated a new transaction key and implemented the new key and API Login ID into our WooCommerce site.

Now I'm receiving an error - https://madshot.net/d45e51487b0e.png - and we HAVE tried multiple other cards and gift cards and receiving the same error. There is nothing wrong with the cards we've tried and I'm having a hard time figuring out what is the connection error issue per any of the woocommerce support documents I have found.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

[Response Code 206](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/responseCodes.html?code=206) suggests you have a configuration problem with your merchant account.  You might want to contact customer support to confirm your gateway and merchant account are setup properly.